# Can I toggle code in Expression Web 4.0

Tags: microsoft-expression-web

I'm looking for some add-in for Expression Web 4.0, in case it exists. Is it possible to toggle code inside a div or a table, similar as visual studio allows?

Example of Visual Studio with toggle functionality:

[image]

Example of a web page in Expression Web 4.0 without toggle functionality:

[image]